# Why can a date object be subtracted from another date object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
var a = new Date(someDateString);
var b = new Date(someOtherDateString);

console.log(b - a); // Outputs for example 3572, number of millisecs between the dates
```

Why does this work? This is an arithmetic operation on two objects. It looks suspiciously like operator overloading, known from C++ and other languages, but as far as I know, JavaScript won't get that before ECMAScript 7.

One would think the JS engine would turn it into something like

```
console.log(b.toString() - a.toString());
```

but this prints "NaN", as toString on a dateobject returns a string on the format

```
Mon Mar 23 2015 13:21:33 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

So, what magic makes this arithmetic possible? Can it be implemented on custom objects?

Comment: Try implementing it and see what happens. JS engines know types, and JS is full of syntactic sugar and auto-conversions--this is no different.

Comment: ticks, the date is represented through a number, based on a starting point (1/1/1970?) and when substracting the dates from eachother, you are implicitely substracting the ticks from eachother, leaving you with the difference between the dates...

Comment: Method valueOf of Date returns a number. When you perform subtraction Date obj is casted to number though.

Comment: Read the ECMAScript 5.1 spec and you'll get your answer

Comment: What would the result of, say `'2015-02-10' - '2014-10-12'` look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It converts them through `.valueOf()` not `.toString()`. Internally a date is stored as a number. The `toString()` method just formats it using a date formatting routine.

See [The Subtraction Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2) in the spec.

Answer (score 1):

[`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) is called to fetch the numeric primitive of the date:

```
function o(i) {
    this.valueOf = function() { return i; }
}

var a = new o(100);
var b = new o(42);

alert(a - b); // 58
```

Answer (score 0):

A JS Date Object is just "a number of milliseconds".

"Zero time" starts at 01 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.  Everything else is a simple conversion, and adding/subtracting become very easy!

Comment: It's an object, not a number. Please don't oversimplify.